Is this a known construction in category theory?
Consider an endomorphic functor $I$ from a category $\mathcal{C}$ to itself.  So for any two objects $L, M$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and morphism $\phi: L \rightarrow M$,
$$
\begin{array}{3}
L & \dashrightarrow & I(L) \\
\downarrow{\phi} & & \downarrow{I(\phi)} \\
M & \dashrightarrow & I(M)
\end{array}
$$
In the example that suggested this question, the category is the category of (order) lattices, and the morphisms are lattice homomorphisms.  The functor takes a lattice to its lattice of (downward, lattice) ideals, where the ideals are ordered by set inclusion.  The functor's action on homomorphisms is:
$$ I(\phi)(X) = \bigcup_{x \in X} M(\phi(x)) = \{ y \in M\,|\,(\exists x \in X)\,y \leq \phi(x) \}  $$
where $M(x)$ is the principal ideal of $M$ generated by $x$.  In particular, $I(\phi)(L(x)) = M(\phi(x))$ for any $x \in L$, and $I(\phi)$ is a natural extension of this subset of values to all of $I(L)$.
Now let there be an associated family of morphisms, $i_L: L \rightarrow I(L)$ for every $L$ in $\mathcal{C}$ such that for any morphism $\phi: L \rightarrow M$, $i_M \circ \phi = I(\phi) \circ i_L$, that is, this diagram commutes:
$$
\begin{array}{3}
L & \stackrel{i_L}\rightarrow & I(L) \\
\downarrow{\phi} & & \downarrow{I(\phi)} \\
M & \stackrel{i_M}\rightarrow & I(M)
\end{array}
$$
In my example, $i_L: L \rightarrow I(L): x \mapsto L(x)$ maps each element to the principal ideal it generates.
Question 1:  Is this combination of an endomorphic functor and an associated family of morphisms a known construction in category theory?
Now consider a second endomorphic functor $F$ on $\mathcal{C}$ with associated family of morphisms $f$ such that for any morphism $\phi: L \rightarrow M$, $f_M \circ \phi = F(\phi) \circ f_L$.  We do not require any particular relationship between $I$ and $F$, though.
In our example, $F$ maps each lattice to its lattice of filters (dual ideals, upward ideals), ordered by reverse set inclusion.  Thus $L$ is the smallest element of $F(L)$ and $\{1_L\}$ (where $1_L$ is the largest element of $L$) is the largest element of $F(L)$.  $F$ maps each $\phi$ by
$$ F(\phi)(X) = \bigcup_{x \in X} M[\phi(x)] = \{ y \in M\,|\,(\exists x \in X)\,y \geq \phi(x) \}  $$
where $M[x]$ is the principal filter of $M$ generated by $x$.  In particular, $F(\phi)(L[x]) = M[\phi(x)]$ for any $x \in L$.  The associated family of morphisms is $f_L: L \rightarrow F(L): x \mapsto L[x]$.  Note that $F(L)$ must be ordered by reverse set inclusion so that $f_L$ is a homomorphism rather than a dual homomorphism.
Let us consider the family of objects $X(L)$ in $\mathcal{C}$, where $X$ is any composition of zero or more copies of $I$ and/or $F$.  Among these objects, we can construct a large set of morphisms.  For example:
$$
\begin{array}{5}
L & \stackrel{i_L}\rightarrow & I(L) & \stackrel{f_{I(L)}}\rightarrow & FI(L) \\
\downarrow{f_L} & & \downarrow{f_{I(L)}} & & \downarrow{f_{FI(L)}} \\
F(L) & \stackrel{F(i_L)}\rightarrow & FI(L) & \stackrel{F(f_{I(L)})}\rightarrow & FFI(L) \\
\downarrow{i_{F(L)}} & & \downarrow{i_{FI(L)}} & & \downarrow{i_{FFI(L)}} \\
IF(L) & \stackrel{IF(i_L)}\rightarrow & IFI(L) & \stackrel{IF(f_{I(L)})}\rightarrow & IFFI(L)
\end{array}
$$
(1) For any $X(L)$ and $Y(L)$, we can assemble chains of these morphisms from $X(L)$ and $Y(L)$ to $XY(L)$, and (2) (though I haven't worked out all the details yet) any two chains of these morphisms from $X(L)$ to $YX(L)$, when each is composed, yield the same morphism.  Thus, these morphisms make the objects $X(L)$ into a direct system, and we can construct its direct limit $L^* = \varinjlim_X X(L)$.
Thus, for every $X(L)$, it is "embedded in" $L^*$ in that there is a canonical morphism $\pi_{X(L)}: X(L) \rightarrow L^*$.  The embedding "identifies" elements of the $X(L)$ such that all $i_X(L)$ and $f_X(L)$ "become the identity", that is, $\pi_{IX(L)} \circ i_{X(L)} = \pi_{X(L)}$ and $\pi_{FX(L)} \circ f_{X(L)} = \pi_{X(L)}$.
Clearly, this can be generalized to any number of pairs of functor and associated morphism.
Question 2:  Is this method of creating a direct limit a known construction in category theory?
This question is based on a construction in Day and Herrmann, "Gluings of Modular Lattices", Order, 1988.

Do you know what a natural transformation is?

Question 1: yes, it's called a pointed endofunctor.

If $F$ is a pointed endofunctor which preserves $\omega$-indexed colimits, then (if I recall correctly) the colimit $L\to F(L)\to F^2(L)\to \dots$ is the free $F$-algebra on $L$ in the sense of the linked nLab article. My guess is that (assuming $I$ and $F$ both preserve directed colimits) your colimit is simultaneously an $F$-algebra and an $I$-algebra, and it is the free simultaneous $F$-algebra and $I$-algebra on $L$. But I would have to check the details.

Thanks for correcting my question, @AlexKruckman!  Thanks for the pointer, @NaïmFavier!

It turns out that the right concept is indeed a pointed endofunctor.  Unfortunately, when I was writing up a clean description of the "general construction" involving two or more endofunctors, it turns out that you don't automatically get a large tree of objects with a natural direct system of morphisms between them.
